# javascript change text when change width device

Tags: javascript, html, responsive

Hi everyone I would like to change the writing that comes on the screen when the width of the device changes, I made this code in javascript, but it doesn't change the writing and gives me only the last option correct.

```
var heightDevice = document.getElementById('startup-animation').offsetHeight;
var widthDevice = document.getElementById('startup-animation').offsetWidth;
console.log(widthDevice);

if (widthDevice <= 480) { //smartphone
  document.getElementById('TextStartUp').innerHTML = 'touch the screen to continue.';
}
else if (widthDevice <= 768) { //tablet
  document.getElementById('TextStartUp').innerHTML = 'touch the screen to continue.';
}
else if (widthDevice <= 1024) { //tablet landscape
  document.getElementById('TextStartUp').innerHTML = 'touch the screen to continue.';
}
else if (widthDevice <= 1680) { //laptop
    document.getElementById('TextStartUp').innerHTML = 'Press any key to continue.';
}
else if (widthDevice > 1680) { //desktop
    document.getElementById('TextStartUp').innerHTML = 'Press any key to continue.';
}
```

Comment: Its an old technique (the way you are going about it) and can work. But have you looked into responsive design and media queries? Both can be used in combo for certain scenarios as needed, the javascript way for quick fixes.

Comment: Is it just to change the text, not the style of the page, with media queries I can change the text, or do you suggest to make several paragraphs and show on the screen only the one concerned with media queries?

Comment: Try with window.innerWidth instead and see what is the outcome :)

Comment: Fixing on @ImranRafiqRather comment wont solve your problem because your logic is faulty

Comment: CHEERS @GetSet ! You are right :)

Comment: I dont know. I might be wrong @ImranRafiqRather on re-examination. ... *pause* Yeah I know I'm wrong on running again in my head. .... I think the keyword in this question from OP is the word "changes": Unless there is an event that triggers this code to run again on a "change", it probably only runs once, and on load

Comment: https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/poEOvWP Try to open this folks ! Just two checks required

Comment: There are actually CSS only solutions to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894291/how-to-change-text-not-font-size-according-to-screen-size-in-css/39894493

Comment: Javascript can mimic the CSS solutions, but I agree, why bother with it @Dollique? There are certain quick fixes where js does do the deed

Comment: This should be done via css media queries as someone already suggested. Render every possible text in a span or something and show/hide it via css only. Imagine it's not just text but several other elements on the page - you don't want to have to run JS code every time the window width changes.

Comment: I do agree with u nice people on taking a CSS Media Query approach. May be OP do not want additional HTML in code. But still, we can achieve the same with pseudo element and media query right in the CSS file as well :) So, I agree with you Guyz... Javascript solution for this small thing is an overkill :)

Comment: OP has yet to respond, so @ImranRafiqRather its just us friendly looking at the possibilities

Comment: @GetSet : A good time together where ideas flourish ( May be this was exaggeration ! May be I am being humorous ) IDEAS FLOURISH as if we have conquered Mars :) But I feel it's great to have discussions and learn from one another in general :)

Comment: Indeed @ImranRafiqRather

Comment: This is the pure CSS Solution that came to mind. And have provided that also to make claim of fellow developers more meaningful :)  https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/poEOvWP?editors=1100  Curiosity never goes away when I get curious

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I have provided a Javascript solution but for this small task, I believe going with javascript is an overkill.

You can try this Pure CSS Solution in which your HTML stays the same and this will be performant also. No Javascript is needed then.

**PURE CSS SOLUTION:**

```css
#TextStartUp{
  position:relative;
}
#TextStartUp::after{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  content:"touch the screen to continue"
}

@media(min-width:1024px){
  #TextStartUp::after{
     content:"Press any key to continue."
  }
```

```html
<div id="TextStartUp"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT SOLUTION:**

You don't require these many checks to show two text messages. Below code sums it up with just two if-else conditions. Try to resize your window :)

```js
if(window.innerWidth<=1024){
  document.getElementById('TextStartUp').innerHTML = 'touch the screen to continue.';
}

if(window.innerWidth >1024){
     document.getElementById('TextStartUp').innerHTML = 'Press any key to continue.';
}
 
// To see changes try to resize developer console

window.addEventListener("resize",()=>{
    if (window.innerWidth <= 1024) { //tablet landscape and below screens
    document.getElementById('TextStartUp').innerHTML = 'touch the screen to continue.';
}
else if (window.innerWidth > 1024) { //laptop and above screens
    document.getElementById('TextStartUp').innerHTML = 'Press any key to continue.';
}
})
```

```html
<div id="TextStartUp"></div>
```

Comment: True. But I want to add that whole concept of "touch the screen" or "press any key" on arbitrary screen sizes (per device) is kinda crazy on a UI/UX level. Considering keyboards can be connected to smaller devices. The message should simply mention both.

Comment: There are events for screen touch and key press also :) But Browser supports may vary. But  yes achievable :)