# How would I change the display for an option in a html select when the screen width changes

Tags: html, reactjs

I am creating a HTML select (drop down) that is for 2 weeks worth of days. The display of it on desktop would look like "Monday - 01/01". I would like to change the days of the week from being the full name to the abbreviation when the screen width gets smaller. So Monday goes to Mon, Tuesday goes to Tue, etc. I am doing this in React so something that might only work there would also be solve my problem.

EDIT
I have 2 different versions of the pull down right now but I would like only one so that I can grab the data to send back to an api.

```
<GridDayTime>
    <GridPullDownDay id='dateDrop' defaultValue={date.getDate()}>
        {dates.map((d) => (
            <option key={d.month + '/' + d.date} value={d.year + '-' + d.month + '-' + d.date}>
                {d.dayName + ' - ' + leadingZeroBuilder(d.month) + '/' + leadingZeroBuilder(d.date)}
            </option>
                ))}
    </GridPullDownDay>
            <GridPullDownDayAB id='dateDrop' defaultValue={date.getDate()}>
                {dates.map((d) => (
                    <option key={d.month + '/' + d.date} value={d.year + '-' + d.month + '-' + d.date}>
                        {d.dayNameAb + ' - ' + leadingZeroBuilder(d.month) + '/' + leadingZeroBuilder(d.date)}
                    </option>
                ))}
    </GridPullDownDayAB>

export const GridPullDown = styled.select`
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: fit-content;
`

export const GridPullDownDay = styled(GridPullDown)`
    @media (max-width: ${({ theme }) => theme.medScreen}) {
        display: none;
    }
`

export const GridPullDownDayAB = styled(GridPullDown)`
    display: none;

    @media (max-width: ${({ theme }) => theme.medScreen}) {
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 7px 12px;
        margin: 10px;
        width: fit-content;
    }
`
```

Comment: What have you tried?  You should share sample code.  This has also been asked before : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894291/how-to-change-text-not-font-size-according-to-screen-size-in-css

Comment: My question is a bit different and I have done something similar right now. Having 2 of the same pull down solves the issue with display but now I have to tackle the issue of which one do I grab the data from. I do appropriate you input and feed back.